# Dual space of continuous functions and meaning of $\langle u,\phi \rangle$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

**Definition.** Let $D(\Omega)$ be the vector space of $C^\infty$ functions with compact support in $\Omega$ and $D^\prime$ be its dual space. A linear mapping

$$
u:D(\Omega) \ni \phi \mapsto  \langle u,\phi \rangle_{D^\prime, D} \in \mathbb{R},\text{or} \hspace{1mm}\mathbb{C}
$$
is a distribution on $\Omega$ if and only if ...

---

My question is specifically about the notation $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$. Does $\langle u,\phi \rangle$ mean inner product of $u$ and $\phi$? It cannot be a inner product since $u$ and $\phi$ are in different spaces and according to inner product they must be in the same space. So what does $\langle u,\phi \rangle$ represent(or mean)?

More importantly, a **concrete example** for my question above would be really helpful!

Comment: That notation is used to say a functional (or a distribution) is *acting* on $u$, in my experience. For whatever reason it is preferred (by some) to just writing $\phi(u)$. Inner products can also be thought of as shadows of this, by representation theorems

Comment: Excuse me ^ I mixed up the arrangement of $u,\phi$ there because I’m used to seeing $\phi$ for functional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U, V, W$ be three vector spaces over $F$.

Then the map $B:U\times V\to W$ which is linear in the both slot is called a bilinear map.

$B_u:V\to W$ and $B_v:U\to W$ is linear for all $u\in U$ and $v\in V$ respectively.

If $W=F$ , then the bilinear map $B:U\times V\to F$ is called a bilinear pairing.

We denote $B(u, v) $ by $\langle u, v\rangle$.

---

Example: $V$ be a vector space and $V'$ is it's dual.

Then $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle :V'\times V\to F$ defined by $$\langle f, v\rangle=f(v) $$

is a bilinear pairing.

---

In particular ,

$D(\Omega)$: space of all test functions.

$D'(\Omega) $ : Continuous dual of $D(\Omega) $

$\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle :D'(\Omega)\times D(\Omega)\to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $$(u,\varphi)=\langle u, \varphi\rangle$$

is a bilinear pairing.

---

Suppose $f\in L^{1}_{\textrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ then $
\langle u_f, \varphi\rangle=\int_{\textrm{supp}(\varphi) }f(t) \varphi(t) dt$

Comment: $\langle f, v\rangle=f(v)$ or $v(f)$?

Comment: Corrected......

Comment: If you expand(explain more) your last example $\langle u_f, \varphi\rangle=\int_{\textrm{supp}(\varphi) }f(t) \varphi(t) dt$ I will accept your answer.

Comment: @FreeMind See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Locally_Integrable_Function_defines_Distribution) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Let me mention a few comments.

Let $E$ be a real vector space, and $F$ a subspace of the set of linear forms on $E$.

1. It is important to notice that

$\begin{array}{rcl}
E \times F &\rightarrow &\mathbb{R}\\
(v,\lambda) &\mapsto &\lambda(v)\\
\end{array}$

is a bilinear map. Moreover, it is quite common, in bilinear algebra, to denote bilinear maps by brackets, or parentheses, etc. so this justifies a bit the notation.

2. Consider now a subspace $G$ of the space of linear forms on $F$; moreover, assume that for every $v \in E$, $eval_v := \lambda \mapsto \lambda(v)$ is in $G$. That is, $G$ can be thought as a kind of *bidual* of $E$.

We then trivially have, for all $v,\lambda$, $\langle eval_v,\lambda\rangle = \lambda(v) = \langle \lambda ,v\rangle$. That is, if we identify $v$ and $eval_v$, we get, for all $v$ and $\lambda$, $\langle \lambda,v\rangle = \langle v,\lambda\rangle$. That is, in this precise sense, $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is kind of symmetric!

3. Assume moreover that $E$ comes with an inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_E$. Now, for every $v \in E$, we can build a linear form $\lambda_v$ by the formula $w \mapsto \langle v,w\rangle_E$. Keeping using this notation, we have, for all $v,w \in E$, $\langle \lambda_v,w\rangle = \langle v,w\rangle_E$. If we identify $v$ with $\lambda_v$, we just get, for all $v,w \in E$, $\langle v,w\rangle_E = \langle v,w\rangle$.
4. Mentally speaking, it can sometimes be fruitful to think of linear forms on a vector space $E$ endowed with an inner product as *generalized vectors*. The notation $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ helps.

Now, take $E := D(\Omega)$ be the space of continuous, compactly-supported functions on $\Omega$ and $F$ be the space of continuous linear forms on $E$, that is, $F$ is the space of distributions. Define $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_E$ to be the integral of the product. Then all I've said applies. Moreover, distributions were invented to serve as *generalized functions*! More precisely, if one is not able to prove that some PDE's have solutions, it is sometimes easier to prove that they have *generalized solutions*, that is, there are *generalized functions* that are solutions to a variant of the PDE, and only then (sometimes) prove that these generalized functions are in fact real ones. As far as I understand, this is the *philosophy* behind distributions.

In summary, at a first glance it might look that $\langle \lambda,v\rangle$ is just a fancy variant for $\lambda(v)$; but the graphical symmetry of the notation $\langle \lambda,v\rangle$ sticks much better to the intuition of *generalized things*.

Answer (score 1):

$ \langle u, \phi \rangle$ is simply the value of $u$ at $\phi$. For example if $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure on $\Omega$ then $\langle u, \phi \rangle=\int_{\Omega}\phi d\mu$ defines  distribution $u$, a special case of this being $\langle u, \phi \rangle=\int_{\Omega} f(x)\phi (x) dx$ where $f$ is an integrable function on $\Omega$ w.r.t Lebegue measure.

Answer (score -2):

it's just a mark, which represents $u(\phi)$

Comment: I made a mistake. $u(\phi) $